# Indentation inside algorithmic environment

Tags: indentation, algorithmic

Consider the following snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=8.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{parskip}
\pagenumbering{gobble}



\begin{document}
    \hrule
    \smallskip
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State Initialize $Q$ to hold all pairs $(w_i,w_j)$ s.t. $v_i$ and $v_j$ are T-C
        \While {Sequence size is bigger than 1}
        \State Find T-C pair $(w_i,w_j)$ s.t. $w_i+w_j$ is minimal
        \State Combine $v_i$ and $v_j$ to a new node $v_k$, and form new sequence (if $v_i$ and $v_j$ are non-adjacent, let $v_k$ take the left position in the resultant sequence)
        \State Update $Q$ accordingly
        \EndWhile
    \end{algorithmic}
    \smallskip
    \hrule
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following:

[image]

How can I indent the lines in **step 4.** to be aligned with the other lines in the While loop?
I tried breaking them with `//` or adding `\hspace{}` but this didn't work...

Comment: Possible duplicates: [How to wrap lines correctly inside `algorithmic`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200186/5764); [Indentation of continued lines in `algorithmicx`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118471/5764)

Answer (score -1):

Try `\State \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\algorithmicindent}{long sentences}`

Comment: Use backticks to highlight inline code. Unfortunately you have not answered the question, or explained what you are trying to do, so people will mark you down....